# KARATE API TESTING : not able to print response array which I am trying to get from If statement and wanted to pass it to next api call request url

Tags: arrays, for-loop, if-statement, eval, karate

step 1 : I am getting one variable in response of one API call which I stored in one variable

```
    * def ID = response.id
```

step 2 : In the second API call, response is the array of json object with multiple fields, after post method response I am trying to pass 'ID' inside if condition and based on if condition I am expecting array ( which is coming empty)
example response of API [ {city: "NY", code:41049, id: ABC-123, name: "USA"},{city: "OT", code:42049, id: ABC-123, name: "CANADA"}

- def idarray = []
  And eval for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++) if (response[i].id == '+ ID +' && response[i].name == 'USA') idarray.add(response[i].cityname)
  Then print idarray ( getting null value)

step 3: I want to pass step 2 printed array value of specific index in next API call urlpath (I am trying like)

And path dynamicform/'+ idarray +'/form1 ( getting null value here for +idarray+)
when method get
then status 200

Comment: Thank you peter for your quick answer . but I am trying to get city's in the array based on id and names. is there any way to get it with where given two conditions satisfied or passed. my code is working fine if I put only one condition in if statement but again challenge is passing that in next API call path.

Comment: I have nothing to add to my answer. you can assume that karate does not support what you want. or you can ask a new question with a better example (and better formatting) and try again. karate is flexible, you need to understand how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use JS loops. They get you into trouble, please refer to the docs for better approaches: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#loops

Also JsonPath will give you what you need in 90% of the situations without needing loops. Please read the docs carefully and look for `JsonPath`.

```
* def ids = $[*].id
* match ids == ['ABC-123', 'ABC-123']
```

I also doubt whether concatenating ids into the `path` will work the way you expect. Please take the help of someone who knows JS if needed.

Maybe you are looking for this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#jsonpath-filters

```
* def fun = function(x){ return x.name == 'USA' } 
* def filtered = karate.filter(response, fun)
* def id = filtered[0].id
```